# Executed procedure not inserting row

Tags: oracle, error-handling, plsql, procedure

Im trying to run a `procedure` where if the `PK` is `null` then `insert variables`.  I executed the `procedure` and didnt receive an error, but when I go to look at the `table` its still empty. Here is the code I have:

```
declare
  type tempcursor is ref cursor;
  v_cur_result tempcursor;
  errcode number;
  errmesg varchar2(1000);
begin
  ct_cu_act_um_pg.spt_save_casedetail
  (null, 8172923, 'SRVCTYPE_CARDPULREHB', systimestamp, 23861881, systimestamp,
  systimestamp, 'CASESTS_COMPL', 'CASESTSCAT_CLSD',
  23778805, 'SRCSRVC_URGNT', 'RESOLS_TRMNTREND', 23778805, 'SRVCDESC_BEDTOIL', 'Y', 'ADAM WAS HERE', 23778805, 'PLCSRVC_OTH', 'N',
  'ADAM', v_cur_result, errcode, errmesg);
end;
```

The spec is below:

```
procedure spt_save_casedetail (
p_casedetailid_in             in casedetail.casedetailid%type,
p_primarymemberplanid_in      in casedetail.primarymemberplanid%type,
p_servicetypecd_in            in casedetail.servicetypecd%type,
p_notifydt_in                 in casedetail.notifydt%type,
p_assignedentityid_in         in casedetail.assignedentityid%type,
p_startdt_in                  in casedetail.startdt%type,
p_enddt_in                    in casedetail.enddt%type,
p_casetypemnemonic_in         in casedetail.casetypemnemonic%type,
p_casestatusmnemonic_in       in casedetail.casestatusmnemonic%type,
p_odsorderingproviderid_in    in casedetail.odsorderingproviderid%type,
p_sourcemnemonic_in           in casedetail.sourcemnemonic%type,
p_caseresolutionmnemonic_in   in casedetail.caseresolutionmnemonic%type,
p_odsservicingproviderid_in   in casedetail.odsservicingproviderid%type,
p_serviceitemmnemonic_in      in casedetail.serviceitemmnemonic%type,
p_providerinnetworkind_in     in casedetail.providerinnetworkind%type,
p_detailtxt_in                in casedetail.detailtxt%type,
p_odsfacilityvendorid_in      in casedetail.odsfacilityvendorid%type,
p_servicelocationcd_in        in casedetail.servicelocationcd%type,
p_facilityinnetworkind_in     in casedetail.facilityinnetworkind%type,
p_audit_user_in               in casedetail.updatedby%type,
p_return_cur_out              out sys_refcursor,
p_err_code_out                out number,
p_err_mesg_out                out varchar2);
```

I spoke to someone and they said something about opening the `cursor` but Im not sure exactly how to do that so ill be looking into it.  Anyways any nudge in the right direction is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind I figured it out, it wasnt being inserted because the service type cd couldnt be found.  Once I changed it to a different type, it was inserted.